# Wifi stops working after I close laptop. Macbook Pro + Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, macbook-pro

Without fail, I boot into Ubuntu and everything is working, but after closing the laptop the wifi stops working. When I restart everything works again.

Running iwconfig, before restarting, gives me this:

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

I am very new to Ubuntu, so any help will be very appreciated!

Macbook Pro (Retina, mid 2014)

Answer (score 2):

Wireless stops working after suspend, I think this is what you're looking for it's on this page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro11-1/Saucy lot's of good info here.

create a file

1. `sudo nano /etc/pm/sleep.d/99_myfix`

put the following into the file

2. `#!/bin/sh`

   ```
   case "$1" in
   resume|thaw)
           service network-manager stop
           rm /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
           service network-manager start
           ;;
   esac
   ```

and set its permission to 755

3. `sudo chmod 755 /etc/pm/sleep.d/99_myfix`

Comment: Would this work on other computers too (Dell XPS)? I've been having this problem

Comment: btw this still works for ubuntu 19 on a macbookpro 2015.

Comment: actually this works for suspend, but if I leave my early 2015 macbook pro suspended for long enough it hibernates, and then I needed the fix here https://askubuntu.com/a/893823/456289

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue with your wifi firmware. Here's an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/624746/194207) to a similiar question that might help you:

> Download the brcmfmac43602 firmware from the Linux firmware git repo
>
> Copy it to /lib/firmware/brcm
>
> Reboot and enjoy your WiFi.