# Macbook Pro (Mid 2015) Wifi [14e4:43ba] doesn't work on 15.10

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom, 15.10, macbook-pro

I have a fairly new Macbook Pro and I installed Ubuntu 15.10 on it recently. Unfortunately, I can't seem to connect to WiFi.

I determined the chipset through the terminal:

```
$ lspci -nn | grep 0280
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC [14e4:43ba] (rev 01)
```

I also can't see any 5GHz networks (not sure if that's a related problem). I've tried to fix it by following the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/622988/wifi-issues-with-macbook-pro-retina-early-2015-12-2-on-ubuntu-15-04), where I downloaded the [brcmfmac43602 firmware](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.bin) from the Linux firmware git repo, and then copied it to `/lib/firmware/brcm`. After rebooting my machine, I'm still unable to connect to WiFi.

EDIT:

Some diagnostics as follows

```
$ dmesg | grep brcm
[    8.822365] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[    8.847342] brcmfmac 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.txt failed with error -2
[    9.331289] brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware version = wl0: Nov 10 2015 06:38:10 version 7.35.177.61 (r598657) FWID 01-ea662a8c
[    9.372960] brcmf_cfg80211_reg_notifier: not a ISO3166 code
[    9.377900] brcmfmac 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[   10.485443] brcmf_add_if: ERROR: netdev:wlp3s0 already exists
[   10.485446] brcmf_add_if: ignore IF event
[   10.624878] brcmf_add_if: ERROR: netdev:wlp3s0 already exists
[   10.624886] brcmf_add_if: ignore IF event
```

Seems like it couldn't load the firmware. Also, why did my network interface get renamed from `wlan0` to `wlsp3s01`? Would like to leave it as `wlan0` if possible.

```
$ lsmod | grep brcmfmac
brcmfmac              282624  0
brcmutil               16384  1 brcmfmac
cfg80211              548864  1 brcmfmac
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add diagnostics: `dmesg | grep brcm` Is the correct driver loaded? `lsmod | grep brcmfmac` If not, load it and try the diagnostic again: `sudo modprobe brcmfmac`