# wifi problem on MacBook pro early 2015 running Ubuntu LTS 16.04

Tags: wireless, 16.04, mac

Abstract:

Ubuntu detects wireless interface, but menu does not show any wireless network.

Details:

I have installed Ubuntu on MacBook pro early 2015. The appropriate drivers for my wifi are installed (according to this question [WIfi Issues with Macbook Pro Retina Early 2015 (12,2) on Ubuntu 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/622988/wifi-issues-with-macbook-pro-retina-early-2015-12-2-on-ubuntu-15-04)). My device is

```
~$lspci -nn | grep 0280
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC [14e4:43ba] (rev 01)
```

and it seems, that Ubuntu sees wireless interface

```
~$ sudo lshw -C Network
*-network               
   description: Network controller
   product: BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=wl latency=0
   resources: irq:18 memory:c1400000-c1407fff memory:c1000000-c13fffff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: NetXtreme BCM57762 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
   logical name: ens9
   version: 00
   serial: ac:87:a3:38:54:a8
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm vpd msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 duplex=full firmware=57762-a1.10 ip=130.223.51.185 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:19 memory:cda00000-cda0ffff memory:cda10000-cda1ffff memory:c1a00000-c1a0ffff
```

Therefore I do not get, why the menu with possible connection does not show any wireless networks (only Ethernet cable). I also installed next to unity KDE, and in the both cases, the list is blanc.

I also tried to install what is recommended here, [Ubuntu can't detect wifi networks on macbookpro 13.3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453252/ubuntu-cant-detect-wifi-networks-on-macbookpro-13-3/453669) but without any change of output (it is different wifi if I understood right, not wonder it has not worked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reinstalled OS and then this solution https://askubuntu.com/a/624746/492421 have worked. I am sorry, but my question is a duplicate.

Comment: My experience was same @KamilSJaron . Reinstall + sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source fixed it for me. This is Ubuntu 17.04 on Macbook pro 11,1

Comment: It depends on the wireless adapter. Some of them need `wl`, some need others.

Answer (score -1):

Connect to the internet using LAN/Phone USB tethering. Then issue the following commands.

```
sudo apt install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43legacy-installer
sudo modprobe brcmfmac
sudo modprobe brcmutil
sudo modprobe brcmsmac
```

Comment: I kind of solved the problem already. But, if you want this answer to be useful for others, you might want to explain what the commands so and why it might resolve problem with wi-fi.

Comment: The instructions mentioned in the accepted answer didn't work on Macbook Pro (Ubuntu 16.04). Hence I added these commands.

Comment: b43-fwcutter installs necessary broadcom firmware to enable the wifi device. modprobe ensures that the appropriate kernel modules are loaded in the system.

Comment: This answer is wrong. 1) Installing `b43-fwcutter` doesn't do anything useful without installing the firmware itself. 2) `b43-fwcutter` doesn't install firmware for `brcmfmac`or `brcmsmac`. 3) Modprobing all broadcom related modules you know is not useful.

Comment: The instructions I used worked for me, hence added them as a possible answer. I don't think it is a wrong answer. Please review your comments.

Comment: Install either firmware-b43-installer or firmware-b43legacy-installer