# Macbook Pro 16.04 wifi driver Installed but not available

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04, macbook, macbook-pro

On both Ubuntu and Ubuntu Gnome, I have working wifi in the installer, but not after. There is no wireless device in the network settings, and I've tried the following with no luck:

[WIfi Issues with Macbook Pro Retina Early 2015 (12,2) on Ubuntu 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/622988/wifi-issues-with-macbook-pro-retina-early-2015-12-2-on-ubuntu-15-04/624746#624746)

[wifi problem on MacBook pro early 2015 running Ubuntu LTS 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772282/wifi-problem-on-macbook-pro-early-2015-running-ubuntu-lts-16-04)

Here are some details:

```
$ lshw -C Network
   *-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlp3s0
   version: 01
   serial: f4:5c:89:8e:0f:79
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmfmac driverversion=7.35.177.61 firmware=01-ea662a8c latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
   resources: irq:63 memory:c1400000-c1407fff memory:c1000000-c13fffff
```

and

```
$ lspci -nn | grep 0280
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC [14e4:43ba] (rev 01)
```

Edit: It seems Ubuntu is incorrectly treating the adapter as wired on every reboot. Closing and re-opening the lid seems to temporarily fix it for whatever reason.

Answer (score 5):

After a "fresh" installation of Ubuntu 16.04, the driver for my wifi hardware Broadcom Corporation bcm4322 was not detecting any wifi networks in my MacBook Pro (Core 2-Duo from 2010).

Fortunately, while being connected through wired Ethernet I  found a work around:

- go to **System Settings | Software & Updates**, then pick the **Additional Drivers** tab.
- There was a section "Broadcom Corporation: BCM4322 802.11 a/b/g/n wireless LAN Controller" with an UNSELECTED radio button labeled "Using Broadcom 802.11 wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel-source (proprietary)" and also a SELECTED radio button labeled "Do not use the device". The only thing I did is clicked the former UNSELECTED radio button and within a few minutes it got the wifi connections worked perfectly