# Can't connect to WiFi on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04

I've been using Ubuntu 16.04 for a few weeks now, and today, all of a sudden, I was unable to connect to WiFi. I'm able to see a list of connections, however, I'm unable to connect -- after entering the password, it tries to connect but fails, and prompts for the password again. This happens 3 times, after which, nothing happens and I'm unable to connect. No change has been made on my router, as far as I know. The funny thing is, even when I use my Android phone to hotspot, I can't connect as well. All other devices in my network have no issues connecting.

My Ubuntu 16.04 is dual boot with Mac OSX, on which, I am able to connect to WiFi without any issues.

Here's some additional information about my wireless adapter.

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 01
       serial: a4:5e:60:d8:b0:2d
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmfmac driverversion=7.35.177.61 firmware=01-ea662a8c latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:50 memory:a0800000-a0807fff memory:a0400000-a07fffff
```

Would anyone be kind enough to troubleshoot this issue with me, please?

EDIT: More information from `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC [14e4:43ba] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC [106b:0152]
    Kernel driver in use: brcmfmac
```

Output of `dmesg | grep brcm`:

```
$ dmesg | grep brcm
[    4.218449] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[    4.340534] brcmfmac 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.txt failed with error -2
[    4.823183] brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware version = wl0: Nov 10 2015 06:38:10 version 7.35.177.61 (r598657) FWID 01-ea662a8c
[    4.883035] brcmf_cfg80211_reg_notifier: not a ISO3166 code
[    4.888248] brcmfmac 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[    5.245395] brcmf_add_if: ERROR: netdev:wlp3s0 already exists
[    5.245398] brcmf_add_if: ignore IF event
[    5.378646] brcmf_add_if: ERROR: netdev:wlp3s0 already exists
[    5.378649] brcmf_add_if: ignore IF event
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I've added the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/a/624746/167850

Comment: Unfortunately, that answer did not help me at all. I'm still getting the exact same behaviour :(

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: `dmesg | grep brcm`

Comment: I've added the output of `dmesg | grep brcm` :)

Comment: I have the same adapter on a "MacBookPro12,1" (Ubuntu only, OSX sucks) and WiFi works fine... but a couple months ago suspend stopped working, and the only errors in `dmesg` are brcmf-related. It always shows that `brcmf_cfg80211_reg_notifier: not a ISO3166 code` ... :-/