# Getting working wifi on macbook air? (Broadcom BCM4360, ubuntu 16.05, wireless-info included)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, broadcom

After some recent software updates, which included a bunch of linux header files my wifi stopped working. At first it was showing up as `UNCLAIMED` in `lshw`, which I thought ment there was no driver for it. After following the steps [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/624746/666427) it was no longer unclaimed, but still not working. I then tried both of the answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592555/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers-for-chip-id-bcm4360-pci-id-14e443a0), the first one didn't work because `apt` couldn't find `bcmwl-kernel-source` (I have tried updating it). The second one appeared to work but did not result in wifi.

So I downloaded and ran the [wifi-issues script](https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info) and im posting the results here in the hope that there is some aspect of this I have failed to understand, and you can enlighten me.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 26 Jul 2018 11:37 BST +0100

Booted last: 26 Jul 2018 00:00 BST +0100

Script from: 10 Jan 2018 20:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.15.0-29-generic #31~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 18 08:54:04 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

\\boot\vmlinuz-4.15.0-29-generic, ro, initrd=boot\initrd.img-4.15.0-29-generic

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [106b:0117]
    Kernel modules: bcma

0a:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57762 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1682]
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. NetXtreme BCM57762 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [106b:00f6]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05ac:8406 Apple, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0781:5583 SanDisk Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ac:0291 Apple, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 05ac:828f Apple, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

cfg80211              622592  0

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

ens9      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'ens9' [IF1]>  
          inet addr:10.15.46.24  Bcast:10.15.47.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::606c:cc7f:6e17:f91/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1683 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1294 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:741429 (741.4 KB)  TX bytes:200117 (200.1 KB)
          Interrupt:19 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:694 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:694 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:61991 (61.9 KB)  TX bytes:61991 (61.9 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

ens9      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.15.47.254    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens9
10.15.46.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     100    0        0 ens9
152.78.111.198  10.15.47.254    255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 ens9
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 ens9

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search soton.ac.uk

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       920     1  0 11:31 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         ens9
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Broadcom Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        NetXtreme BCM57762 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         tg3
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 3.137
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               57762-a1.10
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'ens9' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:05:00.0/0000:06:03.0/0000:08:00.0/0000:09:00.0/0000:0a:00.0/net/ens9
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       ens9
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       912792a3-e3ff-3196-af7c-ec5a4d93ba96
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     1000 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{26}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   912792a3-e3ff-3196-af7c-ec5a4d93ba96 | Wired connection 1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         10.15.46.24/23
IP4.GATEWAY:                            10.15.47.254
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 152.78.111.198/32, nh = 10.15.47.254, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             152.78.110.110
IP4.DNS[2]:                             152.78.111.81
IP4.DNS[3]:                             152.78.111.113
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          soton.ac.uk
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        subnet_mask = 255.255.254.0
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        server_name = 152.78.129.65
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        domain_name_servers = 152.78.110.110 152.78.111.81 152.78.111.113
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        ip_address = 10.15.46.24
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        filename = boot\x64\wdsnbp.com
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 152.78.111.198
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       broadcast_address = 10.15.47.255
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       routers = 10.15.47.254
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       domain_name = soton.ac.uk
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       expiry = 1532602130
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       host_name = henry-MacBookAir
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       network_number = 10.15.46.0
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       next_server = 152.78.129.65
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 900
DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                       requested_host_name = 1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::606c:cc7f:6e17:f91/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/GWR WiFi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=GWR WiFi | type=wifi | permissions=user:henry:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=GWR WiFi
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/_The Cloud]] (600 root)
[connection] id=_The Cloud | type=wifi | permissions=user:henry:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=_The Cloud
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/SWR WiFi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=SWR WiFi | type=wifi | permissions=user:henry:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=SWR WiFi
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Old Thorns]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Old Thorns | type=wifi | permissions=user:henry:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Old Thorns
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/0ad]] (600 root)
[connection] id=0ad | type=wifi | permissions=user:henry:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=0ad
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Southern_WiFi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Southern_WiFi | type=wifi | permissions=user:henry:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Southern_WiFi
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/DonnaAlfredBen]] (600 root)
[connection] id=DonnaAlfredBen | type=wifi | permissions=user:henry:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=DonnaAlfredBen
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/BTWifi-Starbucks]] (600 root)
[connection] id=BTWifi-Starbucks | type=wifi | permissions=user:henry:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=BTWifi-Starbucks
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<<Lovely Leon>>]] (600 root)
[connection] id=<<Lovely Leon>> | type=wifi | permissions=user:henry:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=<<Lovely Leon>>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/The Old Thorns]] (600 root)
[connection] id=The Old Thorns | type=wifi | permissions=user:henry:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=The Old Thorns
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/eduroam]] (600 root)
[connection] id=eduroam | type=wifi | permissions=user:henry:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=eduroam
[802-1x] ca-cert=/etc/ssl/certs/QuoVardisRootCA2.crt
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/BTOpenzone-Starbucks]] (600 root)
[connection] id=BTOpenzone-Starbucks | type=wifi | permissions=user:henry:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=BTOpenzone-Starbucks
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/EMFCSC]] (600 root)
[connection] id=EMFCSC | type=wifi | permissions=user:henry:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=EMFCSC
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/first-wifi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=first-wifi | type=wifi | permissions=user:henry:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=first-wifi
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Thames-Travel-Wi-fi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Thames-Travel-Wi-fi | type=wifi | permissions=user:henry:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Thames-Travel-Wi-fi
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/SKYA893C]] (600 root)
[connection] id=SKYA893C | type=wifi | permissions=user:henry:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=SKYA893C
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/SU(3)xSU(2)xU(1)]] (600 root)
[connection] id=SU(3)xSU(2)xU(1) | type=wifi | permissions=user:henry:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=SU(3)xSU(2)xU(1)
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/virgintrainswifi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=virgintrainswifi | type=wifi | permissions=user:henry:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=virgintrainswifi
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/SouthwestTrainsWiFi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=SouthwestTrainsWiFi | type=wifi | permissions=user:henry:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=SouthwestTrainsWiFi
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/BTWiFi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=BTWiFi | type=wifi | permissions=user:henry:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=BTWiFi
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/LectureHall1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=LectureHall1 | type=wifi | permissions=user:henry:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=LectureHall1
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Premier Inn Free Wi-Fi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Premier Inn Free Wi-Fi | type=wifi | permissions=user:henry:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Premier Inn Free Wi-Fi
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/VirginTrainsEC-WiFi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=VirginTrainsEC-WiFi | type=wifi | permissions=user:henry:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=VirginTrainsEC-WiFi
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/CrossCountryWiFi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=CrossCountryWiFi | type=wifi | permissions=user:henry:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=CrossCountryWiFi
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### Netplan config ####################

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/London (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

ens9      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

ens9      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-29-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     D5B0789D4C423C81CCFB437
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       4.15.0-29-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

facetimehd

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bdc_pci.conf]
blacklist bdc_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf]
options hid_apple fnmode=2

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[  127.843901] tg3 0000:0a:00.0 eth0: Tigon3 [partno(BCM957762) rev 57766000] (PCI Express) MAC address <MAC 'ens9' [IF1]>
[  127.843908] tg3 0000:0a:00.0 eth0: attached PHY is 57765 (10/100/1000Base-T Ethernet) (WireSpeed[1], EEE[1])
[  127.843913] tg3 0000:0a:00.0 eth0: RXcsums[1] LinkChgREG[0] MIirq[0] ASF[0] TSOcap[1]
[  127.843917] tg3 0000:0a:00.0 eth0: dma_rwctrl[00000001] dma_mask[64-bit]
[  127.847956] tg3 0000:0a:00.0 ens9: renamed from eth0
[  127.877265] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): ens9: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[  130.849445] tg3 0000:0a:00.0 ens9: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex
[  130.849464] tg3 0000:0a:00.0 ens9: Flow control is off for TX and off for RX
[  130.849468] tg3 0000:0a:00.0 ens9: EEE is enabled
[  130.849491] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): ens9: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: @chili555 your quite right, that is the solution. Can I ask how you knew that they were the same issue? There are lots of questions on this site relating to drivers, wifi and broadcom, so you must see another element  (probably many others)  to this problem.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 plus kernel version 4.15.0-29 is a known issue. I work with wireless and especially Broadcom nearly every day for about fifteen years. I know, I need to get a life!

Comment: @chili555 from my pov you current life activities are 10/10.  Next time I will check for info relating to my kernal version when I have problems with updates.  I didn't know what a kernal was until you mentioned the word, I've done some reading and I think I get the basic idea now. Thanks for the advice.